# Synthesized naturally

Tags: riddle, word, enigmatic-puzzle

> The City of Sheep and their Shearers,
>   where Kings are born in the presence of Angels.
>
> And the Colossi smiling in the Sand Canyon,
>   just half a Devil away, Make
>
> A PhD with a Lone Star label--
>   an author with a meticulous style.
>
> Or a Roman-Greco Canan miracle.

---

Hint:

> The fourth section is pretty obscure. It likely will only be found after the answer is known. Consider it a bonus-- you only need the first three parts anyway.

Comment: This looks alright, but I think it could be improved if you could say what the object of this is? (e.g. 'What am I/it?')

Comment: Hmm... clues on what sort of puzzle this is already exist in the title and in the riddle(?) itself. Hopefully it isn't just clear in my own mind.

Comment: Maybe you should add the [tag:enigmatic-puzzle] tag?

Comment: Is that definitely [Canan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canan), and not a typo for e.g. Canaan/canon/cannon/canyon?

Comment: Yes. Though nothing on that Wiki page will help you much.

Comment: Good one @Pyrotrain. A line about what is it being sought (a thing / imaginary concept / exists / extinct now etc.) could be helpful

Comment: I'm not sure *being helpful* is quite the goal...

Comment: For what it's worth, despite that hint the fourth line is the only one for which I'm at all confident I know what any part of it means. (I can think of possible kinda-explanations for the first two lines that kinda-fit together, but they *don't* lead to making any sense of the third or fourth.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer is

> $\LaTeX$.

```
The City of Sheep and their Shearers,
where Kings are born in the presence of Angels.
```

> Los Angeles, or **LA** for short. See kayzeroshort's answer.

```
And the Colossi smiling in the Sand Canyon,
just half a Devil away, Make
```

> **Tech** giants in Silicon Valley. (Again, see kayzeroshort's answer.) About 333 miles away from LA (half of 666, as per my earlier answer).

```
A PhD with a Lone Star label--
an author with a meticulous style.
```

> Put 'em together, using a Greek chi rather than "ch", and you get the typesetting system $\LaTeX$. It is used to produce documents (hence an "author", kinda). It is configured and extended by means of "style files", which may be why "with a meticulous style"; or this may just be because if you're after high-quality typesetting you're more likely to be able to get it from LaTeX than from, say, Microsoft Word. The TeX is presumably the "Lone Star label". (In fact it turns out that the OP was thinking of the .tex filename suffix rather than the TeX on the end of "LaTeX" as such, though of course they refer to the same thing.) Why "a PhD", though? Perhaps because LaTeX is used a lot in academia? Perhaps because the creators of both LaTeX (Leslie Lamport) and the underlying typesetting system TeX (Donald Knuth) are PhDs? I'm not sure I understand this bit.

```
Or a Roman-Greco Canan miracle.
```

> The "La" on the front is made of ordinary Roman characters. The "TeX" at the end is made of Greek ones (tau, epsilon, chi). Perhaps "Canan miracle" is just an oblique way of saying "marriage" (see my earlier answer for why).

Incidentally, anyone inclined to upvote this should consider (1) upvoting kayzeroshort's answer, which solves the first stanza that I would never in a million years have cracked and (2) un-upvoting my earlier answer if they upvoted it, because there's no reason I should get double credit for this.

Comment: Cheers! Thought this riddle was dead and gone ;) PhD was a poor hint as well, meant to be read as 'doc' or document, suffixed with a ".tex" (Lone Star label).

Comment: Aha! Yeah, I understood the "lone star" bit, though I was thinking of it as the tail end of "LaTeX" rather than as a filename extension ... though I see I omitted to actually say so in my answer. I'll edit that in.

Answer (score 5):

**Partial Answer**

I'm pretty sure the first two stanzas refer to

> Los Angeles and San Mateo.

The City of Sheep and their Shearers,
where Kings are born in the presence of Angels

> The Rams (sheep), the Clippers ("shearers"), the Kings, and the Angels are all Los Angeles-based professional sports teams in the NFL, NBA, NHL, and MLB, respectively.

And the Colossi smiling in the Sand Canyon,
just half a Devil away.

> So, the "Sand Canyon" is likely Silicon Valley, and San Mateo happens to be 333 miles away from Los Angeles, which fits the "half a Devil", i.e. half of 666, clue suggested by @GarethMcCaughan. I'm not sure what the Colossi refer to: could be "tech giants" of silicon valley, or the San Francisco Giants baseball team (though that takes us away from San Mateo).
> It's also interesting because San Mateo, i.e. St Matthew, carries on the gospel theme.

Unfortunately, I don't have a path towards a final answer.

Comment: Dead right! Answer to first paragraph is the city, answer to the second paragraph deals with the sort of colossi. Combine them to get the PhD with a lone star label, which/who is an author with a meticulous style.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial and probably-wrong answer**

Well, it's been about a day with no obvious progress, so let me set down what little I have in case it helps someone else. (Or in case writing it down makes it easier for my brain to spot things.)

[EDITED after the OP offered a comment on the original version of this answer and also updated the puzzle.]

The City of Sheep and their Shearers,
where Kings are born in the presence of Angels

> Given the fourth line, this has a lot of echoes of the Christian "Nativity" -- except that (1) "Bethlehem" means "house of bread" or possibly "house of meat" rather than anything to do with sheep, though the most famous people alleged to have come from there are King David, who was literally a shepherd, and Jesus, who is metaphorically described that way, and (2) in the nativity story Jesus's birth is announced by angels but none are mentioned at the event itself. So I *suspect* this is misdirection and something else is going on, but I don't know what. (No obvious sign of sheep, shearers, or angels involved in the birth of Elvis Presley, for instance :-).)

The Colossi smiling in the Sand Canyon,
just half a Devil away

> Perhaps "half a Devil" is 333 (miles? kilometres? a road numbered 333?) on account of the one bit everyone knows from the Book of Revelation. (Or perhaps 308, since the number might actually be meant to be 616 rather than 666.) But strictly that's the number of "the Beast" which is not necessarily quite the same thing as the Devil. Perhaps instead we need to take the name of a particular devil, or a particular name for the devil (Mephistopheles, Satan, ...) and halve it somehow. As for the Colossi in the Sand Canyon, I don't know. There are some places literally called Sand Canyon but they don't seem to have colossi. Maybe grinning in the Sand Canyon -> sinning in the Grand Canyon or something, but there's no wordplay tag on the puzzle.

... make
A PhD with a Lone Star label--
an author with a meticulous style.

> I still have no idea what's going on here. Does "meticulous style" mean that the author is renowned for precision? Or is it "style" in the sense of "label" or "title"? In view of the apparent Christian themes elsewhere (though, again, I suspect at least some of them are red herrings) it's worth saying that some Christians like to call the author of the third gospel "Doctor Luke", since he was apparently a physician, and to comment favourably on the accuracy and elegance of his writing. And, well, there's a character called Lone Starr in the comedy movie *Spaceballs*, who is kinda a parody mashup of *Luke* Skywalker and Han Solo from *Star Wars*. But I think this is again probably all coincidence. (If not, I remark that the puzzle comes in four parts, and the Cana story is in the *fourth* gospel ... but I don't see any very obvious way to turn the first bit of the puzzle into Matthew or the second into Mark.)

The Roman-Greco Canan miracle

> must surely somehow be a reference to the biblical story of Jesus turning water into wine at a wedding at *Cana*. "Roman-Greco" is a curious term, and I don't know whether we should attach any significance to the writer's choice of this over the maybe more natural "Romano-Greek". At any rate, the fact that we have Roman-Greco rather than Greco-Roman surely indicates that whatever's Roman precedes whatever's Greek. Is there perhaps some relevant word formed from one Roman (= Latin) and one Greek element? The two examples that come to mind have them the other way around (homo/sexual, tele/vision; both are Greek-then-Roman). Or some relevant people, one Roman and one Greek?

**Known to be wrong, preserved in case useful**

I wondered whether

> the city of sheep might somehow refer to the *Faroes*, and the colossi in the sand canyon to the *Pharaohs* -- note the similarity in sound. But, unsurprisingly, OP has confirmed that this is mere coincidence.

Comment: Your interpretation of line four is pretty much spot-on. The rest is in the wrong direction, however. I'll be updating the riddle shortly, to give a little more to go on.

Comment: That's roughly what I expected (see my comments on the question itself) :-).

Comment: Man, I feel like I'm gonna owe you an apology once the answer is found. Your answer goes in a much more interesting direction than mine! You have quite a few of the pieces, however. If you believe anything else should be answered/clarified, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my guess is

> Sphinx (of Egypt)

Here is an attempt

The City of Sheep and their Shearers, and

> It is the town of Betlehem (linked with Jesus Christ and perhaps even prior) this structure was built well before Jesus ...(to be explained / linked properly)

the Colossi smiling in the Sand Canyon,

> the huge structures of Pyramids looking across the deserts (sand Canyon)

make A PhD with a Lone Star label,

> to be explained / linked ...

or a Roman-Greco Canan miracle.

> It is a miracle of the Ancient Greeks to conceive a creature made of human, animal (**CANINE** for dog) and bird  !

Comment: Clever direction, but incorrect.